# XNA project won't target .NET 4.0

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, windows-phone-7

I am trying to reference the System.Threading.Task assembly. If I am not mistaken, it should be part of mscorlib. But no matter what I do, my project always defaults to the .net 2.0 runtime. Even if I create a brand new XNA 4.0 Windows Phone project, it wants to use the .net 2.0 runtime. Any ideas what I could be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone is limited to C# 3.0 and .NET 3.5. You have to use the [Task Parallel Library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks) to achieve this.